# Xfce Power Manager on Xubuntu 13.10 doesn't work

Tags: xubuntu, power-management, xfce

The problem is that its actually works, but something works with Xfce Power Manager at the same time. For example, I set that if I pressed Suspend button (on my Lenovo B560 its Fn+F2 hotkey) then system ask me what to do. But when Log out window appears, system goes to suspend. Another example is closing the lid. I set it to lock the screen via Xfce Power Manager, but system still goes to suspend. I thought that it might be laptop-mode-tools, but it's not installed. Before 13.10 I had 13.04 and everything were fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the problem of it suspending when it should not be upon closing of the lid, i believe that editing

/etc/systemd/logind.conf,

changing the following line to read as such:

HandleLidSwitch=ignore

fixed it for me.